# Can one factorise a covariance matrix analytically or iteratively?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, covariance

I have a covariance matrix which I would like to factorise. In more details, I would like to represent it in the following form:

$
m \approx f \cdot f^T + diag(d^2), 
$

where $diag(d^2)$ means that I calculate element-wise square of vector d and then use it to construct a squared diagonal matrix.

For example, $m$ (the original covariance matrix) might be 100 by 100, $f$ could be 100 by 3 matrix and $d$ is a 100 dimensional vector.

Is there a fast way to do it? Analytical solution would be great. An iterative procedure is also good.

I need to add, that I minimise mean squared deviation between the elements of original covariance matrix and elements of its approximate representation (given above).

Comment: It seems like if f is only 100x3 the rank of the resulting matrix wouldn’t be enough

Comment: Wouldn't be enough for what?

Comment: You might find it interesting to take a look at [Polar decomposition of real matrices](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2020/index.htm).
In your case, the orthogonal part of the polar decomposition is the unit matrix. I'm affraid, though, that it doesn't properly solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can't do this with arbitrary d.
To prove this it's enough to see that $f^T f + diag(d^2)$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, while your covariance matrix can have $0$ determinant.

You might want to checkout the Cholesky decompostion. If you take away the $d$ vector and just focus on $f$, you end up with $m \approx f^T f$. You can calculate one such $f$ matrix for non-singular covariance matrices numerically without using any approximations.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question, I search for an approximation. So, if my approximation does not have a 0 determinant and the original matrix has, it is ok as soon as the approximate representation is closes to what is being represented. Moreover, in all my practical cases m has non-zero determinant.

Comment: In a [Cholesky_decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), the resulting matrix $f$ is __triangular__,
which is not by far resemblant to the say $100\times 3$ matrix as is asked for in the question.